# Java Priority Queue Interface Implementation

Tags: java, data-structures

This were the questions I was asked in the interview fews days back and I was not sure about the approach. Suggestions would be highly appreciated:

How can I have implement PriorityQueue interface to get queue() method in O(1) and dequeue() method in O(n).

How can I have implement PriorityQueue interface to get queue() method in O(n) and dequeue() method in O(1).

Thanks.

Comment: that's a tough question, I hope the position was a reputable one.

Comment: @mdma - Are you kidding or you really mean your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A typical PriorityQueue implementation would use a Heap to get O(lg n) performance for the "add" operation, so O(n) performance will be even easier.

For example, you could use a vector or linked list as the underlying data structure.  For O(1) "add" you can simply add the new value to the end and for O(n) "remove" you can do a linear search for the min value.  Conversely, for O(n) "add" you can do a linear scan to find the next largest value then insert before it, for O(1) remove you can simply remove the first element of the list.

Answer (score 2):

queue() method in O(1) and dequeue() method in O(n):

Use a linked list and simply add every new entry directly to the head of the list in queue(). In dequeue() iterate the list and remove and return the entry with the highest priority.

queue() method in O(n) and dequeue() method in O(1):

Use a linked list again. But this time in queue() you iterate over the entries to put the new entry into it's priority sorted position (this is actually one step of an insertion sort). In dequeue() you can now always remove and return the first element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at:

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.java.html

Remember, all good programmers copy good code :P

I assume you have the basic understanding about data structures, list, maps, etc. If you dont, understanding how this work will not make much sense, instead go and investigate about the subject further.

Answer (score 1):

I would have said that PriorityQueue isn't an interface, it's a class, and I wouldn't implement anything that was O(n) if I could help it.

Answer (score 0):

For an O(1) approach to the queue() method you must keep track of the last element of your queue, so that you can easily append one more after it, regardless the size of your queue.

For an O(n) in queue() and O(1) in dequeue() you need to keep track of the first element of your queue in a variable, so that regardless the number of elements within it, you can remove the first from the list with always a single set of instructions (no iterations).

In each of both cases you just add one extra variable to your class.

Comment: can you give an code example for the same ? Its hard to understand here.

Comment: Well, I don't have one handy right now, but you can easily make one by making an implementation of a Java PriorityQueue made by yourself, with Nodes.
Make a node class, where a node is an entity with an object, and a reference to the next node.
Then make a list, which has got a reference to the first node/last node [depending on if you want O(1) for the queuing  or dequeuing or both], and then it's done!
I don't know how the core Java's PriorityQueue class is implemented, but it might as well be implemented in this way or something similar. Checking the source might turn out to be an example.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a solution for this--

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Naive_implementations

For O(1) insertion, add element to the current location and for dequeue in O(n) perform a search based on priority..

For O(n) insertion perform the search initially based on priority and add the element and for dequeue in O(1) just remove the element from the beginning or from 0th location...

The code in this example can help you understand more clearly.

http://www.java-forums.org/java-lang/7449-how-implement-priority-queue-java.html

In the above example, the dequeue takes O(1) and insertion takes O(n)